# How to provide a function in a Racket environment on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: export, racket, procedure

I want to execute a program (written in Racket) on the raspberry pi but when doing so, he doesn't know functions that are defined in another file.

The small example below gives rise to following error on the raspberry pi : 
*default-load-handler: expected a 'module' declaration for "test", found: something else in: ...*

File I'm executing on the raspberry pi :

```
(require "test.rkt")
(display "2 + 2 = ")
(display (plus 2 2))
```

The "test.rkt" file :

```
(provide plus)
(define (plus a b)
  (+ a b))
```

When executing the file it doesn't display anything but immediately gives rise to the error listed above.

Note that my files don't contain : "#lang racket".
Because if they contain it, loading the file will simply do nothing.

So following file does nothing when loaded on the raspberry pi :

```
#lang racket ; When omitting this "Hello World!" is displayed, else not
(display "Hello World!")
```

Comment: Are you *sure* that's what test.rkt looks like? What happens if you `cat test.rkt`?

Comment: You're right, I accidentally sent the wrong "main" file (the one that calls "plus"). Now I sent the correct main file, which looks like the one above. And i get another error. I updated my post with the error.

Comment: Are you sure nothing happens? It works fine on a PC. Maybe the "Hello World!" is getting line-buffered. Try `displayln` instead of `display`.

Comment: Yes, I tested it again to be sure. When beginning the file with `#lang racket` and then doing a display or displayln, nothing happens (it immediately returns without displaying "Hello World!").

Comment: Are you loading it with `(load "test.rkt")` or `(require "test.rkt")`? I get the behavior you're describing when I use `load`, but it works fine when I use `require`. Also, you can't `require` a file that doesn't have the `#lang` line. That would give rise to the error you were originally asking about.

Comment: Indeed, when I load it using "require" it works as it should be. Thanks for your help!